# IHost extension in .Net6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, .net-5

I am trying to migrate an IHost extension for EF Seed migration from .Net5 to .Net6 . Can you please lead me the proper way to do this conversion.

```
 public static class HostExtensions
    {
        public static IHost MigrateDatabase<TContext>(this IHost host,
                                            Action<TContext, IServiceProvider> seeder,
                                            int? retry = 0) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            int retryForAvailability = retry.Value;

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                <code removed for brevity>                 
            }
            return host;
        }
    }
```

The extension is being called in .Net5 as follows:

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .Build()
                .MigrateDatabase<OrderContext>((context, services) =>
                {
                    var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<OrderContextSeed>>();
                    OrderContextSeed
                        .SeedAsync(context, logger)
                        .Wait();
                })
                .Run();
        }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MigrateDatabase :

```
public static void MigrateDatabase(this IServiceProvider sp)
{
    var loggerFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

    // operations
}
```

Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.Services.MigrateDatabase();

apo.Run();
```

Comment: ⚠️CAUTION: Putting the code here will cause it to execute when running `dotnet ef`. You may want to stick with the Program.Main/CreateHostBuilder approach until [dotnet/efcore#27306](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27306#issuecomment-1128033019) is implemented.

Comment: 'ConfigureHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Build' and no accessible extension method 'Build' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigureHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Getting the above error. Cant find the Build method.

Comment: Decompiling the Host object shows this Build() method:

IHost IHostBuilder.Build()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Call {nameof(WebApplicationBuilder)}.{nameof(WebApplicationBuilder.Build)}() instead.");
        }

Not sure how are you calling the Build method.

Comment: edited the answer, try the new changes :)

Answer (score 0):

use like this in Program.cs :)

```
var app = builder.Build();
 app.MigrateDatabase<WebSocketAcceptContext>();
```

Comment: This will not even compile with code from OP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).